# Program arguments to an array of objects

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, explorer

I am a Java programmer and was in need of a way to reveal multiple files in explorer, so I found a function `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` that allows doing that (explorer CLI only lets to select a single file).

I have composed the code of samples from here and there, and it worked successfully for hardcoded paths, but now I want the program to accept a path of a containing folder as the first parameter and the files to be selected as all the rest.

Here's a hardcoded one.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include "RevealMultiple.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        //Directory to open
    ITEMIDLIST *dir = ILCreateFromPath(_T("C:\\"));

    //Items in directory to select
    ITEMIDLIST *item1 = ILCreateFromPath(_T("C:\\Program Files\\"));
    ITEMIDLIST *item2 = ILCreateFromPath(_T("C:\\Windows\\"));
    const ITEMIDLIST* selection[] = { item1, item2 };

    UINT count = sizeof(selection) / sizeof(ITEMIDLIST);

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    //Perform selection
    HRESULT res = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(dir, count, selection, 0);

    //Free resources
    ILFree(dir);
    ILFree(item1);
    ILFree(item2);

    CoUninitialize();

    return res;
}
```

And here's the code that gives an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include "RevealMultiple.h"
#include <list>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Directory to open
    ITEMIDLIST *dir = ILCreateFromPath(argv[0]);
    const ITEMIDLIST* files = new ITEMIDLIST[argc - 1];

    //Items in directory to select
    std::list<ITEMIDLIST*> filesList;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        filesList.push_back(ILCreateFromPath(argv[i]));
    }

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    //Perform selection
    HRESULT res = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(dir, filesList.size, filesList._Get_data(), 0);

    //Free resources
    ILFree(dir);
    for (auto file : filesList)
    {
        ILFree(file);
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return res;
}
```

But I got an error, obviously:

```
revealmultiple.cpp(25): error C3867: 'std::list<ITEMIDLIST *,std::allocator<_Ty>>::size': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ITEMIDLIST *
1>        ]
```

How do I properly convert array of string arguments to an array of `ITEMIDLIST*`, so I could pass it to SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems?

Thanks for any word of help.

Comment: First of all (and unrelated to your problem) the default container should always be `std::vector`. In this case you don't need what `std::list` has to offer. Secondly, always point out *where* in the code the error is. While finding line 25 might not be to hard with your example, it's still hard enough. Then don't use member-function starting with an underscore and an upper-case letter (like `_Get_data()`) as those are not supposed to be used externally, and are reserved for the implementation. Lastly, what is `filesList.size`? Is it a member *variable*?` You did *read* the error message?

Comment: One more suggestion: Remove all code that is not necessary to demonstrate the issue. Since you get a compiler error, the code doesn't even have to be able to run in a useful way, so stripping most functionality is okay.

Comment: You should read about the concept of RAII. It will help you handle legacy-style APIs like `ILCreateFromPath`/`ILFree`, `CoInitialize`/`CoUninitialize` etc better. Also replace all `new[]`, `sizeof`, and C-style array with proper containers.

Answer (score 0):

First note that argv[0] is the command that was used to invoke the program, the regular arguments start at argv[1].

That being said, something like the following should do what you are after:

```
ITEMIDLIST *dir = ILCreateFromPath(_T(argv[0]);
ITEMIDLIST ** ppItems = new ITEMIDLIST *[argc-2];
for(int ndx = 2; argc > ndx; ++ndx)
  ppItems[ndx] = ILCreateFromPath(_T(argv[ndx]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A container like `std::list`, that does not guarantee that the data is stored as a contiguous block of memory, is unsuitable for working with APIs like `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` that expect a pointer to an *array*.

The only valid choice of standard containers are `std::vector`, `std::array`, plain old array or any manually allocated contiguous block of memory.

Using `std::vector` your code changes to:

```
std::vector<ITEMIDLIST*> filesList;

HRESULT res = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(dir, filesList.size(), filesList.data(), 0);
```

Note that `size()` is a function, not a data member as you treated it in your original code. This is why you got a compiler error. Also with `std::vector` there is no need to use a proprietary member function to get a pointer to the data, `std::vector::data()` is well defined.